# [PL/SQL]how to make a loop that runs multiple procedures

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle-apex, plsql-package

suppose I have a list of procedures p1,p2,p3..pn , each procedure has only one output number parameter,  basically each procedure is a constant number. How could I create a loop that runs all these procedures and the results are displayed on the screen?  I tried with EXECUTE IMMEDIATE something like:

```
DECLARE
 i number;
 n number:=5;
 print number;
begin
 for i in 1 .. n loop
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'BEGIN p'||i||'('||print||') END;' ;
  dbms_output.put_line(print);
 end loop;
end;
```

I also tried the form [EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sql_stmt INTO print USING i]
but I still haven't done anything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's `BEGIN myprocedure; END;` - you're missing the ";" after the procedure call. It's unclear what you want the "print" to do, that is not declared anywhere so it will just print an empty value.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE procedure p1
AS
BEGIN
  dbms_output.put_line('this is 1');
END;
/
CREATE OR REPLACE procedure p2
AS
BEGIN
  dbms_output.put_line('this is 2');
END;
/
DECLARE
 n number:=2;
begin
 for i in 1 .. n loop
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'BEGIN p'||i||'; END;' ;
 end loop;
end;
/

this is 1

this is 2
```